# Doing What I Used to Do in VBA: Cycling Through Controls and Assigning Values Based on Field Names in C# - Possible?

Tags: c#, class, language-features

I've been using MSACCESS and VBA for a few years, but I'm getting excited about C#, WPF and EF 7. I really like C# constructs, they're simple even for me.
There are some things, however, that seem to become necessarily difficult.
I'll give you an example: in VBA I open a recordset to read the data and, if I've given the controls names similar to those of the fields, I can easily cycle through the controls and assign values.

---

```
    Dim db As DAO.Database, rs As DAO.Recordset, ctrl As Control
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("dbo_label", dbOpenDynaset)
    rs.MoveLast: rs.MoveFirst
    rs.FindFirst "[id_eti]='" & Me.Search & "'"
    If rs.NoMatch = False Then
        For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
            If Left(ctrl.Name, 3) = "txt" Or Left(ctrl.Name, 3) = "cc_" Or Left(ctrl.Name, 3) = "img" Then
                ctrl = rs(Mid(ctrl.Name, 4))
            End If
        Next
    Else
        MsgBox "No match for " & Me.Search, vbExclamation, "Warning"
    End If
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing: Set db = Nothing
```

---

As you can see, I can cycle through the controls (and I do this in C# too), assigning each control the value contained in the field, looking for it by the field name.
In c#, EF7 generates a class to access the table, but I haven't found a simple way to access the data using the field name.
Something like:
myTxt.Text == myClass[nameoffield];
where nameoffield is a string variable.
Also, you will see that the field value is assigned to the control regardless of the type of control: in my case they are TextBox, CheckBox and Image controls.
Can I hope for a future update or not?

Comment: You could probably do something similar with reflection, but it's not the WPF way. You need to learn about [Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-7.0)